# TypeScript error with object properties possibly undefined despite checking for undefined values using Object.values()

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

I have an interface `MentionItem` with `id` and `value` properties, both of which are required to be strings. However, TypeScript is giving me an error that these properties are possibly string | undefined.

When I manually check that `id` and `value` are not undefined, TypeScript is happy. However, when I use `Object.values(dataset).includes(undefined)` to check for undefined values, TypeScript still complains.

Why is TypeScript giving me this error, and how can I fix it?

###### Here's my code:

```
  interface MentionItem {
    id: string;
    value: string;
  }

  getItemData = (): MentionItem => {
    const dataset = (this.mentionList.childNodes[this.itemIndex] as HTMLElement).dataset;

    if(Object.values(dataset).includes(undefined)) {
      throw new Error("Incomplete dataset")
    }

    return {
      id: dataset.id,
      value: dataset.value,
    };
  };
```

###### And here is the TS Error:

`Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

I am trying to understand why this gives me an error, since it should achieve the same thing, please correct me if I am wrong:

#### The check that satisfies TypeScript

```
if(dataset.id === undefined || dataset.value === undefined) {
  throw new Error("Incomplete dataset")
}
```

#### The check that upsets TypeScript

```
if(Object.values(dataset).includes(undefined)) {
  throw new Error("Incomplete dataset")
}
```

Comment: By the way, arrow functions don't create new `this`-contexts, so `this` might not refer to what you think it is. Probably not the cause of your problem though.

Comment: @MichaelM. Thank you for reminding me about arrow functions and this-contexts. I am well aware that arrow functions don't create new this-contexts, but I appreciate your concern. I've already learned that lesson the hard way in the past and won't make that mistake again. As the saying goes, "Fool me once, shame on you. Fool Me Twice, Shame on Me."

Comment: There's **countless** ways to check if all values of an object aren't `undefined`. TypeScript won't run your code with numerous inputs to see if it actually works (and how would it even do that?). TypeScript only handles the most common patterns and uses, which `Object.values(x).includes(T)` does not fall under. You can address this issue using a type guard with a type predicate (what's known as a user-defined type guard). This pattern allows you, the developer, to tell TypeScript what your custom check is doing. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mA8nQN) is one possible solution.

Comment: The manual check is more readable, more efficient, more reliable (non-present and non-own/enumerable properties are more common than dynamic ones), and typechecks automatically. You should use it. Or better, start with `const {id, value} = dataset;`.

Comment: What line of code is generating the error - is it in the check that uses the `includes` method, or the return statement that assigns `dataset` properties to the object literal?

Comment: @Ry- I agree, I am asking it to learn why it doesn't work. As someone else also mentioned, in this case the "manual" check is more readable, but I found a library that fixed these "issues" in typescript. Check it out, it's very interesting: https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset

Comment: @traktor It's when I use id: dataset.id, then it's complaining about dataset.id possibly being undefined

Comment: @vr. That sounds interesting, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue rests with the dual use of `undefined` in JavaScript.

1. If you attempt to access an object property that doesn't exist, JavaScript returns the `undefined` value.
2. If you access an object property that does exist but has been set to `undefined`, it also returns `undefined`.

Now `Object.values` returns the values of the own properties of an object, not `undefined` for properties that are not there. Hence

```
if(dataset.id === undefined || dataset.value === undefined) {
  throw new Error("Incomplete dataset")
}
```

works for properties that don't exist on `dataset`, because accessing them returns `undefined`, the condition is met, and the error is thrown, but

```
if(Object.values(dataset).includes(undefined)) {
  throw new Error("Incomplete dataset")
}
```

fails because there are no own properties of `dataset` that have been explicitly set to `undefined` to be found by the `includes` method, the condition is not met, and the error is not thrown.

Comment: This is a very good point, but even if `Object.values(dataset)` did return `[dataset.id, dataset.value]`, TypeScript could not infer the property types from the `.includes()` call

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure the hypothetical changes the answer: the check in the post that "upsets" Typescript" was never going to detect _missing_ `dataset` values in the first place, which I assume is its primary purpose. It should not be used because it doesn't work - IMHO the TypeScript error was a bonus :-)

Comment: Oh of course, you are completely right. Thanks for explaining! I also learned that even if I did this: [dataset.id, dataset.value].includes. that typescript also wouldn't infer the proper types. Matt Pocock made this awesome library, which makes it so that  methods like `filter`, `includes`, etc. are properly understood by typescript https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset